# why body background color not changing

Tags: html, css

I am making a javascript calculator by referring this code on [codepen](https://codepen.io/PizzaPokerGuy/pen/ORyAgG) the problem is that  the body background color is set to black, but why its still in white color. Is there a spacing issue? So far i haven't had experienced this kind of behavior :( and how can i get away from this problem. thanks in advance...

```css
html, body{
    background-color:black;
  }
 
  #calcOutput{
  
    width:250px;
    height:75px;
    border-top-left-radius:2em;
    border-top-right-radius:2em;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-top:20px;
    padding-top:20px;
  }
  
  #calculator{
    background-color:grey;
    width:250px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:2em;
    border-bottom-right-radius:2em;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
  }
  #steps{
    padding-left:50px;
    font-size:2em;
  }
  .bigButton{
    width:93px;
  }
  a{
    margin: 5px;
    width: 2.6vw;
    height: 2.6vw;
  }
```

```html
   
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
     
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     
</head>
<body>
   
    <div class="text-center">
      <h1>Calculator</h1>
      <h2>JS calculator</h2>
    </div>
    <div id ="calcOutput">
      <span id= "steps">0</span>
      <hr/>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center" id="calculator">
      <a class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteAll">AC</a>
      <a class="btn btn-danger" id="backOne">CE</a>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" id="/">/</a>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" id="*">*</a>
        <br/>
     <a class="btn btn-primary" id="7">7</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="8">8</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="9">9</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="-">-</a>
      <br/>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" id="4">4</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="5">5</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="6">6</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="+">+</a>
      <br/>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" id="1">1</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="2">2</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="3">3</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" id=".">.</a>
      <br/>
      <a class ="btn btn-primary bigButton" id="0">0</a>
      <a class ="btn btn-primary bigButton" id="total">=</a>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`), open the Inspector, and see which styles are applied and where they come from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because you are using bootstrap which has a value for the body background which is white, in this case you have two option:

**First Option**

use `!important`

```css
html, body{
    background-color:black !important;
  }
 
  #calcOutput{
  
    width:250px;
    height:75px;
    border-top-left-radius:2em;
    border-top-right-radius:2em;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-top:20px;
    padding-top:20px;
  }
  
  #calculator{
    background-color:grey;
    width:250px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:2em;
    border-bottom-right-radius:2em;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
  }
  #steps{
    padding-left:50px;
    font-size:2em;
  }
  .bigButton{
    width:93px;
  }
  a{
    margin: 5px;
    width: 2.6vw;
    height: 2.6vw;
  }
```

```html
   
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
     
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     
</head>
<body>
   
    <div class="text-center">
      <h1>Calculator</h1>
      <h2>JS calculator</h2>
    </div>
    <div id ="calcOutput">
      <span id= "steps">0</span>
      <hr/>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center" id="calculator">
      <a class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteAll">AC</a>
      <a class="btn btn-danger" id="backOne">CE</a>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" id="/">/</a>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" id="*">*</a>
        <br/>
     <a class="btn btn-primary" id="7">7</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="8">8</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="9">9</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="-">-</a>
      <br/>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" id="4">4</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="5">5</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="6">6</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="+">+</a>
      <br/>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" id="1">1</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="2">2</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="3">3</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" id=".">.</a>
      <br/>
      <a class ="btn btn-primary bigButton" id="0">0</a>
      <a class ="btn btn-primary bigButton" id="total">=</a>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

**Second Option**

In your html page place your customized css reference below bootstrap css reference so your custom css could override bootstrap css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/your/customized/style.css">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works :) , i'll accept answer in 2 minutes